Meaning of '+' symbol at the beginning of branch name in `git branch` output
I'm using git-subrepo. I've created a git subrepo branch and when I run git branch it outputs something like this:
$ git branch
* master
+ subrepo/CurriculumVitae

What's the meaning of that + symbol?
I've researched it unsuccessfully.

In the future, please provide textual commands and output using a code block. Thanks.

The + symbol in front of a branch name in the output of git branch means that this branch is checked out in its own worktree. Use
git worktree list

to see where the worktree is located.
From the documentation:

Any branches checked out in linked worktrees will be highlighted in cyan and marked with a plus sign.


I wondered why I had never seen this, but it's because my most common git installation is a bit too old. Turns out this output feature for git branch appeared around version 2.23.
